# How to create a Duplex stream where unshift works

Tags: node.js

I need to 'splice' stdin/stdout from a child process into a readable/writable stream in Node.JS. I have a function that does this, but I recently learned that calling `unshift` on the `Duplex` doesn't lead to the next read including the unshifted buffer.

Can anyone spot the bug in my code?

```
it("unshift duplex", async function () {
    function splice(readable: NodeJS.ReadableStream, writable: NodeJS.WritableStream): Duplex {
        const duplex = new Duplex({
            write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                writable.write(chunk, encoding, callback);
            },

            final(callback) {
                writable.end(callback);
            },
        });

        // All reads and events come directly from the readable stream.
        duplex.read = readable.read.bind(readable);
        duplex.on = readable.on.bind(readable) as any;

        return duplex;
    }

    readable = new PassThrough();
    writable = new PassThrough();
    duplex = splice(readable, writable);

    duplex.unshift(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3]))
    const result = duplex.read()
    expect(result).toEqual(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3])) // ERROR: Expected null to equal Buffer [ 1, 2, 3 ]
})
```

Comment: Using the `plexer` NPM package and replacing my `splice` function with `duplexer(writable, readable)` makes the test pass. Although in my real-app, unshift still doesn't work. I haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: It looks like the stream was in flowing/unpaused mode, despite having removed event handlers from it, and in such a mode, unshift simply leads to raising the data event (with no handler), so the next *read* call won't retrieve that data.